# Avoid of pyramid of doom

Tags: reactjs

I want to convert code of `testCall` to using of Promise in testCall function for avoid of pyramid of doom, but I don't know how should I do this. I'm appreciate for helping to resolve this.

the code is like below:

```js
const fakeFetch = (a) => Promise.resolve(a === 'works' ? { data: { a: '1'}} : 'nah')

function testCall (a) {
    fakeFetch(a).then(res => {
        if (typeof res !== 'object') {
            throw new Error('Not an object')
        }
        else {
            fakeFetch('works').then(res => {
                if (typeof res === 'object') {
                    console.log('it works')
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: [Async/await in JavaScript](https://JavaScript.info/async-await)

Comment: Without async/await. I want resolve it with Promise @kellys

Comment: How will you escape the pyramid of doom without async/await? The only other way to wait until a promise resolves is a callback and that of course leads to the pyramid of doom.

Comment: Really I don't know. No any way of solution with Promise?